Problemas de comunicación asíncrona entre microcontroladores
tengo un problema de comunicación de forma asíncrona con RS232 entre dos microcontroladores, en el nodo local tengo la opción de elegir si el microcontrolador exhibe una distancia que aumenta o disminuye en su pantalla o si envía el valor de la distancia al nodo remoto, donde se procesa y con respecto a su valor y si aumenta o disminuye hace que un motor gire y su velocidad es controlada con la distancia enviada del nodo local. Estuve probando en nodo local y cuando esta en modo remoto si envía la distancia y si cambia si la aumento o disminuyo, pero en el nodo remoto se queda parado en la parte donde se supone que recibe el valor de la distancia y de ahí no avanza. Para ser específicos se queda en esta instrucción:
gets(buffer); // Recibe el valor de la distancia
#include <16F886.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//#device ADC=10

#FUSES NOWDT                    // No Watch Dog Timer
#FUSES NOBROWNOUT               // No brownout reset
#FUSES NOLVP                    // No low voltage programming, B3(PIC16) o B5(PIC18) used for I/O

#use delay(clock=4000000)
#use rs232(baud=9600, parity=N, xmit=PIN_C6, rcv=PIN_C7, bits=8)

// Definiciones para la pantalla LCD
#define LCD_RS_PIN      PIN_C0                                   
#define LCD_RW_PIN      PIN_C1 
#define LCD_ENABLE_PIN  PIN_A2 
#define LCD_DATA4       PIN_C3                                    
#define LCD_DATA5       PIN_C4                                    
#define LCD_DATA6       PIN_C5                           
#define LCD_DATA7       PIN_A1

#include <lcd.c>

float previous_distance = -1;  // Para almacenar la distancia previa

void setup() {
    lcd_init();
    printf(lcd_putc, "\fNodo remoto\n");
    delay_ms(2000);
    lcd_putc("\fDistancia Rem:");
    //lcd_putc("\fDistancia Rem:\nXX.Y cm  ");
    
    setup_ccp1(CCP_PWM);              // Configuración del PWM
    setup_timer_2(T2_DIV_BY_16, 255, 1); // Configuración del temporizador para PWM
    set_tris_b(0x00);                 // Puerto B como salida para el motor
}

void update_motor(float distance, char direction) {
    int16 pwm_duty;
    
    // Determinar la dirección del motor
    if (direction == '+') {
        output_high(PIN_B0);  // Motor en un sentido (p.ej., sentido horario)
        output_low(PIN_B1);
    } else {
        output_low(PIN_B0);   // Motor en el otro sentido (p.ej., sentido antihorario)
        output_high(PIN_B1);
    }

    // Convertir la distancia a un valor de PWM (a ajustar según tus necesidades)
    pwm_duty = (int16)(distance * 10.23);  // Suponiendo que 100 cm es el máximo y mapea a 1023 (10 bits)

    if (pwm_duty > 1023) {
        pwm_duty = 1023;
    }

    set_pwm1_duty(pwm_duty);  // Ajusta la velocidad del motor
    previous_distance = distance;
}

void main() {
    float distance;
    char direction;

    setup();
    
    while (TRUE) {
        if (kbhit()) {
            char buffer[16];
            gets(buffer); // Recibe el valor de la distancia
            distance = atof(buffer);

            // Determina la dirección en función de la distancia previa
            if (distance > previous_distance) {
                direction = '+';
            } else {
                direction = '-';
            }

            lcd_gotoxy(1, 2);
            printf(lcd_putc, "%.1f cm %c", distance, direction);

            update_motor(distance, direction);
        }
    }
}


Puede ser que se quede esperando a que reciba un caracter de nueva línea '\n' para terminar la lectura y como el nodo no lo envía se queda el gets(buffer) esperando.
